# Periodic continuous functions are bounded using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions

> How do you show that a doubly-periodic continuous function $f:\Bbb C→\Bbb C$ is bounded?

Comment: What about the exponential function $z \to e^z$? Even for doubly periodic you need the entire function.

Comment: Perhaps you mean doubly-periodic? Compare http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244416/proving-that-a-doubly-periodic-entire-function-f-is-constant.

Comment: It is not, unless it is constant.

Comment: @ArpitKansal If the function is doubly periodic and continuous, then it is necessarily bounded. No need for it to be entire, although you do need that it is _defined_ on the whole of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Arthur Ah thanks..it will be constant if its entire.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244416/proving-that-a-doubly-periodic-entire-function-f-is-constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not true unless you mean *doubly-periodic* instead of periodic.

If that *is* what you mean, then here is a **hint:**

1. A continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded (and attains its minimum and maximum).
2. The values of a doubly-periodic function are all equal to the values on some initial parallelogram containing the origin.

Comment: The question says nothing about doubly-periodic functions.

Comment: @mrf But the result is not true without the doubly-periodic assumption. Even $z \mapsto e^z$ will be a counterexample.

Comment: Of course it's not true, but it's just as likely that the OP has misunderstood this (after all, it's true for $\mathbb{R}$) as that (s)he mistook periodic and doubly periodic. Surely, it's better to wait for clarification from the only one who actually knows what they want to ask.

Comment: I don't understand the part 2 of the answer. Would you explain it a little more? Thanks!

Comment: @J.doe let's say the two periods are x and y. Just thinking of them as vectors, all complex numbers z can be written as ax+by for a and b real numbers. Then subtract or add x and y until you get a'x + b'y where a', b' are between 0 and 1. The value of the function is the same since subtracting x or y didn't affect it. The set of z such that z = a'x + b'y and a', b' are between 0 and 1 is a parallelogram.

Comment: Why do we need them to be between 0 and 1?

Comment: @J.doe so we get a compact set.

Comment: So 0 and 1 are just some random numbers right? We just need them to be bounded.

Comment: @J.doe Yeah! That's right. Of course, you can only subtract or add an integer number of $x$s and $y$s, so you can't get it between $0$ and $\frac12$, for example. But instead of between $0$ or $1$, you could get between $-10$ and $10$ or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: @J.doe You're welcome :)