# How do double periodic meromorphic functions behave?

Tags: complex-analysis

Here it's proved that an entire, double periodic function is constant:

[Proving that a doubly-periodic entire function $f$ is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1244416/800134)

I'm thinking about something which is related to that, namely the behaviour of double periodic meromorphic functions. To be more specific, I've been asked to prove that the following holds for such a function $f$ if it's not constantly zero
$$
\sum_p (p \times m_p(f)) \in\omega_1\mathbb{Z} + \omega_2\mathbb{Z}
$$
where the sum is taken over all the zeroes and poles inside the parallelogram
$$
P = \{a\omega_1 + b\omega_2 : 0 \leq a, b \leq 1\}.
$$ So $p$ can be either a zero or a pole, and $m_p(f)$ means the multiplicity or the negative order of $p$.

The function $f$, being double periodic, satisfies
$$
f(z+\omega_1) = f(z+\omega_2) = f(z)
$$ for all $z \in\mathbb{C}$.
Now I don't even know how to start proving the stated property since the formula looks very strange to me and since I can't think of any principle or theorem that would be applicable. Can anyone say something helpful?

Comment: Integrate $zf'(z)/f(z)$ around a parallelogram.