$f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ analytic with $f(z)=f(z+a)=f(z+b)$

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ analytic with $f(z)=f(z+a)=f(z+b)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that f is constant.

WLOG, I'll assume that $a=1;b=i$. Now, we have that $f(\mathbb{C})=f([0,1]^2)$, because given  $w=x+yi; \ x, y \in \mathbb{R}$; $w'=(x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor)+(y-\lfloor y \rfloor)i \in [0,1]^2$, so:
\begin{align*}
&f(w')=f((x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor)+\lfloor{x}\rfloor+(y-\lfloor y \rfloor)i) \\[7pt]
=&  f(x+(y-\lfloor y \rfloor)i+(\lfloor y \rfloor)i)\\[7 pt]
=& f(x+yi)=f(w)
\end{align*}
But as $[0,1]^2$ is compact, $|f|$ attains a maximum for some $z_0 \in [0,1]^2$. But by the property above, $|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|; \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ and as $f$ is analytic, by Maximum Modulus Principle, $f$ is constant.
For other $a,b$, the procedure is analogous, considering $w'=xa+yb; \ x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.
Is this a correct approach; any suggestions?

That's a good approach. Your WLOG argument is really dealing with a special typical case only. For general $a,b$ there is still a small technical gap: what replaces $[0,1]^2$ in that case??

That is the standard proof, compare e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1244421/42969

@HansEngler, it'd be the paralellogram defined by the complex numbers $0,a,b,a+b$ as vertices
