Entire function $f$ such that $f(z_0 +z) =f(z_1 +z) =f(z)$ is constant
Take $z_0,z_1$ $\in \mathbb{C}$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ linearly independent.
The exercise is to prove that if $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is entire such that  $f(z_0 +z) = f(z)$ and $f(z_1 +z) = f(z)$ $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $f$ is a constant function.
From the hypothesis I've managed to prove that $f(n.z_0 + m.z_1) = f(0)$ $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. I feel that this should be enough to at least obtain a similar result for rational coefficients, however I am stuck. The best I was able to do was that if we take $ \gamma =\frac{p}{q}.z_0 +\frac{j}{k}.z_1$ with $p,q,j,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $f(\gamma.q.k) = f(0)$

Such functions are sometimes called "doubly-periodic".  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244416/proving-that-a-doubly-periodic-entire-function-f-is-constant

from yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4898449/f-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-analytic-with-fz-fza-fzb
